# String interpolation into a variable from JSON in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# application where dynamically i get strings in run time with variable names inside it. The variable names are dictionary with key parameter. The dictionary is also getting filled dynamically.

I tried using string interpolation ($) and string.Format but no luck since i am getting that string in run time and also i don't have the number of variables and the names it will have to use format.
PFB the sample scenario.

```
Dictionary<string, string> inputs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
inputs["name"] = "John";
inputs["address"] = "NA"; //the key names are determined in runtime
string url = "xyz.com/zexample/set(person='{inputs[\"name\"]})"; //or
url = "xy.co/set(person='{inputs[\"name\"]},foo='{inputs[\"address\"]}')"
```

Please help me with some solution for this scenario, i need to dynamically replace the {} values with the exact values from dictionary. Also i mentioned the keys in dictionary and the string with {} variables are generated in run time and will be different.

Comment: The question's code doesn't contain any interpolated strings or String.Format calls. Did you forget to add the `$` prefix perhaps ?

Comment: You're missing a `$` before the string and `'` in `"xyz.com/zexample/set(person='{inputs[\"name\"]})"` at the end of the person assignment, same with other string as well. It should be `"xyz.com/zexample/set(person='{inputs[\"name\"]}')"`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, `inputs[\"name\"]` won't even compile

Comment: @Matt.G good catch, I didn't see that TBH and it's such an obvious issue as well.

Comment: @Vignesh, it is mentioned `i am getting that string in run time` in the post. is the string value stored in a variable? assuming the string we get in runtime is stored in variable named `key`, you could try `var url = $"xyz.com/zexample/set(person='{inputs[key]})";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting your URL strings at runtime, so string interpolation won't work. They're coming with the interpolations indicated by `{inputs["name"]}` rather than `{0}`, `{1}`, etc., so never mind String.Format.